# this.props.commands.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, axios

I have a problem rendering my props.command from component somehow an error will occur here is my

```
    import { getCommand } from '../../actions/commandActions';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    class Command extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          commands: []
        };
      }

      componentWillMount(){
        this.props.getCommand();
        this.setState({commands: this.props.commands});
      }


      render(){
        console.log('command props.commands: ', this.props.commands);
        return (
          <table className="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Command</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
              this.props.commands.map(function(commands) {
               return
               <tr>
                <td>{commands.name}</td>
                <td>{commands.command}</td>
                <td>{commands._id}</td>
               </tr>
              })
            }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
      }
    }

    Command.propTypes = {
      getCommand: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      errors: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return{
        commands: state.commandReducer.commands,
        errors: state.commandReducer.errors
      }

    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCommand })(Command);
```

Here is the console.log of this.props.commands:

```
command props.commands:  Array[1]
0: Object_id: "5892c3d4d3128f231ab032bb"
command: "env $(cat .env) DEBUG=ow* APP=sso node index.js"
createdAt: "2017-02-02T05:29:56.392Z"
enabled: true
name: "Frank Command"
timeout: 180000
uri: "http://139.59.60.15/commands/5892c3d4d3128f231ab032bb"
```

I wanted to render it to my table but i got an error of

> this.props.commands.map is not a function

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: since you are anyways saving the props in state, you can map over state as well, try 

`this.state.commands.map` Also `this.props.commands.map` may not be a Javascript object. Try running `this.setState({commands: JSON.parse(this.props.commands)});`

Comment: It is the same `this.state.commands.map is not a function`

Comment: Did you try parsing with JSON.parse and also are you using immutable.js

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Not using immutable js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134658/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-frank-mendez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment it seems that `this.props.commands` initially gives a empty object instead of an array. You can either make change in your code to return the array as props or perform a check. 
Also assign a unique key ot your object like

```
{ Array.isArray(this.props.commands) && this.props.commands.map(function(commands, index) {
               return
               <tr key ={i}>
                <td>{commands.name}</td>
                <td>{commands.command}</td>
                <td>{commands._id}</td>
               </tr>
              })
            }
```

Comment: Hello guys thank you for your answers. I got it by converted my object to array using _.valuesIn(this.props.commands); from lodash (y)

Answer (score 1):

Initially your `commands` is an `object` as you shown in console, Put the check before creating the `ui` items by using `map`, one more thing, whenever creating the `ui dynamically` in `loop` always assign the unique `key` to wrapper, Try this:

```
{ 
  Array.isArray(this.props.commands) && this.props.commands.map((commands,i) => { 
    return 
      <tr key={i}> 
         <td>{commands.name}</td> 
         <td>{commands.command}</td> 
         <td>{commands._id}</td> 
     </tr> 
   }) 
}
```

Comment: app.js:369 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.commands.isArray is not a function